# Show data from database into label

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net

I have database like this:

[image: My Database Screenshot]

How I can set all row into label or hiddenfield, ?
if I use code like this, i just get last data from row database.

```
  While (result.Read())
        Label1.Text = result.Item("StartDateBlock")
        Label2.Text = result.Item("StartDateBlock")
        Label3.Text = result.Item("StartDateBlock")
        Label4.Text = result.Item("StartDateBlock")
    End While
```

*please don't suggest me to use repeater*

Comment: Can you show us what that code gives you and what you want from it?

Comment: is that control a `datagridview` ??

Comment: Sure you see the last row because each row override the previews. Why not repeater? How about [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)